# MongoDB: How to find key by value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using Node.js with express framework and Mongoose (MongoDB), and I have a question about how to effectively retrieve data.

Let's say I have something like this on a mongo document:

```
test : {a:1, b:2, c:2, d:1};
```

It's easy to retrieve the value of keys (a,b,c, or d), but how to do the inverse, for example retrieve all the letters that have value 2 (in my example it would be 'b' and 'c')

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the use case..

Comment: It would be good if you explain the use-case.

Comment: if you would like to find documents that have certain values all with "2", you might want to like into the aggregation framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = {a:1, b:2, c:2, d:1};

var search = function(obj, value) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(test[key] === value) {
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
};

search(test, 2);

//output b c
```

Be careful if you have modified Object.prototype then you could have unwanted prototype keys, and you should control it.